# Do we have RADIANS math function in Salesforce?

Tags: math

i am trying to find nearest stores and their longitude and latitude based on customer location (lon,lat) and populate in Google map. Here is a sample query would work in MySQL. Would this same query work in Salesforce? Do we have **Radians function or equivalent function for Radians in salesforce**? Moreover, is this possible to frame a query like this?

```
 SELECT
`id`,
`name`,
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 AS `distance`
FROM `stations`
WHERE
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 < 10
ORDER BY `distance`
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Baskaran

Comment: This may help: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000092lGIAQ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no radians function available directly in SOQL. However The new release of SOQL includes geolocation cababilities, you do not need to calculate distance yourself. Try something like:

ORDER BY Clause Sort records by distance using a distance condition in the ORDER BY clause. For example:

> SELECT Name, StreetAddress_*c   FROM Warehouse*_c   WHERE
>   DISTANCE(Location_*c, GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'mi') < 20   ORDER
>   BY DISTANCE(Location*_c, GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'mi') LIMIT 10

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm|SkinName=webhelp